# How do you use kable to tidy up a data frame in Shiny output

Tags: r, shiny

I have a data frame `df` with column names containing underscores. I would like to format it using `knitr::kable(df, ...)`. When this is used with `rmarkdown` you can pass it a list of nice column names, and it will also automatically spread the names over multiple lines to make the table fit on page.

However, I am trying to use `kable` with Shiny. That is, I would like a `renderXXX()` type output to write to the `output` object so that I can call my nice table from `ui.R`. I've tried in `server.R`:

```
renderText(

   knitr::kable(df, format = "html")
)
```

and in `ui.R`:

```
htmlOutput("results_table")
```

but this just leads to a very messy table.

Comment: Not sure if it would work, but try using `uiOutput (HTML(knitr::kable (df, format="html")))`.

Answer (score 3):

I think you'll find the full answer here:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kableExtra/vignettes/use_kable_in_shiny.html

**UPDATE**
Using the mtcars dataset as an example, first you add the below to your ui section:

```
mainPanel(
         tableOutput("mtcars_kable")
      )
```

and follow that through in the server section with:

```
library(kableExtra)
   output$mtcars_kable <- function() {
     req(input$mpg)
     mtcars %>%
       mutate(car = rownames(.)) %>%
       select(car, everything()) %>%
       filter(mpg <= input$mpg) %>%
       knitr::kable("html") %>%
       kable_styling("striped", full_width = F) %>%
       add_header_above(c(" ", "Group 1" = 5, "Group 2" = 6))
   }
```

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: @paper1111: added.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a more powerful data table in Shiny, with the ability to extensively customize the appearance, try:

[Using DT in Shiny](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/shiny.html)

Comment: hi Lee. I have tried this but I have found it very hard to configure the column widths. I've tried multiple examples given elsewhere in stackoverflow but have been unable to limit the width of the table in my report.